# how to grab value between two strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a long string(html), and i want to grab each value that is between < td> < /td>, example, i need the strings "avatr","lionking" :

```
<td>avatar</td>  <td> lionking</td> and so on....
```

Comment: @CoderSeven better tell him to use xml parsing before he starts doing string manipulation.

Comment: Well, definitely not by regex.

Comment: @Machinegon luckily there is no downvoting in comments

Comment: Please consider using HtmlAgilityPack ([StackOverflow how-to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack) ) instead of inventing your own solutions.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/MfQjAML.gif) is how it will look if you insists on using regex for xml parser

Answer (score 3):

Because you are parsing HTML (a context-free language), you should not use regular expressions.  For details, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Fortunately, .NET has a great library available for parsing HTML called the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: HTML Agility Pack is great! Also CsQuery looks promising https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

Comment: @bowenl2 My god that link is killing my eyes!